# How do you escape pipe character in bitbucket markdown?

Tags: special-characters, markdown, bitbucket

I would like to add the following to a bitbucket wiki:

```
Key         | Description                                   |Default        |
:-----------|:----------------------------------------------|:--------------|
env         |Execution context {development|test|production}|development    |
```

Markdown has a backslash escape for many characters, but not pipe (|). I saw one solution using `{development&#124;test&#124;production}` but this does not work as you can't use html in bitbucket markdown.

Has anyone found a way to include the pipe character in cell contents in a markdown table on bitbucket?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bitbucket's Markdown might not support HTML, but it does support Unicode. Inside table cells you can use another character that *looks like* the pipe character, e.g. [`⎮` (0x23AE, INTEGRAL EXTENSION)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/23ae/index.htm):

```
Key         | Description                                   |Default        |
:-----------|:----------------------------------------------|:--------------|
env         |Execution context {development⎮test⎮production}|development    |
```

This character won't trigger Bitbucket's Markdown table syntax.

Comment: Ok, so there isn't an escape for pipe? This solution is fine for me, though, so thanks

Comment: @NectarSoft, I wasn't able to find a proper escape.

Comment: This is a good solution, just wish bitbucket would support html entities. Pls vote: https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/6930/support-some-or-all-html-in-markdown-bb